# Eclipse ignores conditional breakpoint (java for hadoop)

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, conditional-statements, breakpoints

This is my java code:

```
public class MoviesReviewsMapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        String [] tokens = value.toString().split("::");        
        context.write(new Text(tokens[2]), new Text(tokens[0]));
    }
}
```

And this is a conditional breakpoint:

[image: Conditional breakpoint]

Version of Eciplse/SDK is v4.7.0. What's the problem?

Comment: I tried also with condition in breakpoint: tokens[2] == "6040", because the last userId in file which is read by mapper is equal to 6040 and same thing happens. Conditional breakpoint is ignored. I'm interesting in that particular breakpoint stop when that condition is actually achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your String like this:

```
"1".equals(tokens[2])
```

The problem is that you're comparing variable references, not the object itself.